# How do I extract the source code from a swf file

Tags: parsing, flash

I want to get the source of the swf file from this site

http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/WTOL-7B6SFC_R0_EN.swf

actually it is the calculator which is used for calculating energy consumption of data center can any one have idea hot to get the source code for this swf file can anyone parse this file for me I'll be very thankful for him for this actually I am developing similar kind of application in visual studio .net for which I need to take idea of farmulas which are used in the backend so  wanted to know what calculations are going behind developing this calculator can anyone parse it for me I'll be thankful for him

Comment: You need to email the author and ask if he can give you the original source code.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a swf decompiler.

Comment: yes @Walfie You're Write i am looking for swf decompiler

Comment: "If you steal someone’s code they can decompile yours to prove it"

Comment: @A.D., your comment is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Technically you can use a *decompiler* to do this job.

There are free (e.g.: [ActionScript Extractor](https://sites.google.com/site/as3extractor/)) and paid (e.g.: [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/)) tools out there.

But, before you do any decompiling processes, note that you **MUST** have permission from the author to see (use or anything else) his code.

I'm not a legal authority here, so what I say **MUST NOT** be used as truth.
And, you may be charged legally if you break an copyright law or something!

Answer (score 0):

[as3extractor](https://sites.google.com/site/as3extractor/) works very well, program is free.