# Trying to get links of an interactive map (Web scraping .swf)

Tags: python, selenium, flash, beautifulsoup

i need to create a web scraper for this [website](http://www.allpetservices.co.uk/search.asp)

However I need to get the links for the counties, stored in the [interactive map](http://www.allpetservices.co.uk/uk_ir_locator.swf)

Unfortunately, for some reason, their search engine doesn't provide all the results as the interactive map does.

**My question:
Could anyone tell me how to get all the links for all the counties, without manually accessing them?**

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: Scraping data from this site is against their TOS... don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Technically you can use a decompiler to do this job.
>
> There are free (e.g.: ActionScript Extractor) and paid (e.g.: Sothink
>   SWF Decompiler) tools out there.

you can reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538578/how-to-get-the-source-code-of-swf-file)

---

**Edit :**
Most swf content gets external records from either a `.xml` or `.json` file.

Without decompiling and just using the browser's Developer Tools we can see that an xml file is indeed accessed (maybe it contains what you want) :

http://www.allpetservices.co.uk/uk_ir_locator.xml.
 
Put `view-source:` in front of the link to read it (if there's an error message).

In that xml you want to extract the contents (the *xyz*) of each & every `<link> xyz </link>` tag. This will give you the **links** of every entry on the map.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. Decided to just update yours instead of making a new Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question: There's no way to get the links from the site.

The solution: The structure of the links you are trying to retrieve are very predictable. They follow the same structure: 
    `http://www.allpetservices.co.uk/search_map.asp?ccounty={COUNTY_NAME}`

So, if you can use another site or data source to get the names of each of the counties, you can formulate each of the links that you need.

Comment: Already thought of that, however some of the website's county names aren't accurate, therefore I'll still end up getting the county names from the website manually.